# How to read off coefficients of tensor-like expression in a speedy way?

Tags: tensors, performance-tuning

I am considering identities involving `t[a, b, c, d, ...]`, where number of indices is fixed. `t` has the cyclic property so that `t[3, 4, 1, 2]` is equal to `t[1, 2, 3, 4]`.

When $k=4$, all possible elements are generated by

```
basis = (# /. {List -> t}) & /@ Permutations[Range[4]];
basis = basis /. {t[a___, 1, b___] -> t[1, b, a]} // Union
```

Here comes the output:

```
{t[1, 2, 3, 4], t[1, 2, 4, 3], t[1, 3, 2, 4], t[1, 3, 4, 2], t[1, 4, 2, 3], t[1, 4, 3, 2]}
```

I want to convert expressions like `t[1, 2, 3, 4] + t[1, 3, 2, 4] - t[1, 4, 3, 2]` into a coefficient matrix to do some linear algebra. I tried the following code:

```
identity = {t[1, 2, 3, 4] + t[1, 3, 2, 4] - t[1, 4, 3, 2], 
  t[1, 2, 4, 3] + t[1, 3, 2, 4], 
  t[1, 3, 4, 2] - t[1, 2, 3, 4] - t[1, 4, 2, 3]};

coeffmatrix = Coefficient[identity, #] & /@ basis // Transpose
```

The output is

```
{{1, 0, 1, 0, 0, -1}, {0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {-1, 0, 0, 1, -1, 0}}.
```

Efficiency does not matter for this small example. However, when I increase number of indices and identities, getting `coeffmatrix` becomes very slow and spends a huge amount of memory. For the real case, `t` has 10 indices and the size of `coeffmatrix` is approximately $362880 \times 362880$.

Here comes my question: Coefficients are always restricted to `{-1, 0, 1}` for some reasons. Would this fact probably help me to boost up the performance? Could anyone give me a suggestion for better efficiency?

Comment: Would using a `SparseArray` help?

Comment: @TobiasHagge I am not familiar with `SparseArray`. What is the benefit to use `SparseArray`?

Comment: more efficient storage and faster computations on matrices for which most of the coefficients are zero.

Comment: @TobiasHagge Is it possible to calculate the matrix rank directly from `SparseArray`?

Comment: I haven't used sparse arrays much, but my understanding is that most of mathematica's linear algebra functions are implemented to transparently work with them. `CoefficientArrays`, by the way, produces a `SparseArray`, so if you want to test performance you can compute the rank using the matrices computed by both your algorithm and Mr. Wizard's, and see which is faster.

Comment: If you try to do something with sparse arrays mathematica can't handle it'll convert the matrix to a non-sparse form before proceeding. In that case sparse arrays are slower than non-sparse.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Is this faster?

```
CoefficientArrays[identity, basis][[2]] // MatrixForm
```

$\left(
\begin{array}{cccccc}
 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0
\end{array}
\right)
$

---

Responding to Jens' elegant answer it should be noted that performance of `CoefficientArrays` is better optimized for this task as one would hope.

```
basis = (# /. {List -> t}) & /@ Permutations[Range[8]];
basis = basis /. {t[a___, 1, b___] -> t[1, b, a]} // Union;

size = {5000, 30};
identity = Total[RandomInteger[{-1, 1}, size]*RandomChoice[basis, size], {2}];

(r1 = CoefficientArrays[identity, basis][[2]];) // RepeatedTiming // First
(r2 = D[identity, {basis}];)                    // RepeatedTiming // First

r1 == r2
```

> ```
> 0.0517
>
> 0.43
>
> True
> ```

In this example the difference in memory consumption is far more significant:

```
ByteCount /@ {r1, r2}
Divide @@ % // N

{1639856, 608080968}

0.00269677
```

Comment: Amazing! It's about 100 times faster than before. Can we do the same linear algebra with `SparseArray`?

Comment: @JoonhoKim post a new question with a specific example and I'll try to answer that.

Comment: Indeed, I noticed similar timing differences with the original example by just repeating it many times.

Answer (score 5):

To convert a list of linear expressions to a matrix containing the coefficients the following is easier to write than `CoefficientArrays`, but seems to be a little slower:

```
D[identity, {basis}]
```

> $$\left(
> \begin{array}{cccccc}
>  1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & -1 \\
>  0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  -1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$$

What I did here is to use the fact that for a linear map the matrix of coefficients is identical to the Jacobian. The latter is what I calculate.

Comment: This is beautiful but in my testing it is slower than `CoefficientArrays`.  I guess you just noticed that too.  It also produces a dense array that could take up quite a bit of memory in some cases.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Yes, my initial timing included the duration of the keystrokes...

Comment: A metric I use myself if you haven't guessed. :D

Comment: You already have my vote but I thought it worthwhile to note the performance caveats so I added an example to my answer.  If you feel it is an unfair example please let me know; I chose it without much consideration.