# Sparse Cholesky Decomposition

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra, sparse-arrays

I am working with square matrices with a special form, which for large rank ($> 100,000$) would be best stored and manipulated as a `SparseArray`.  I believe that the Cholesky decomposition of these matrices itself could also be sparse.  The question I have is

> How do I compute the sparse Cholesky decomposition of a sparse matrix without resorting to dense storage of the intermediates and result?

For purposes of illustration:

```
n = 5;
s = SparseArray[{{i_, i_} -> 2., {i_, j_} /; Abs[i - j] == 1-> -1.}, {n, n}];
s // MatrixForm
```

[image: s]

The `CholeskyDecomposition` function returns a dense matrix:

```
CholeskyDecomposition[s] // MatrixForm
```

[image: Cholesky triangle]

The `CholeskyDecomposition` documentation gives a lead: "Using `LinearSolve` will give a `LinearSolveFunction` that has a sparse Cholesky factorization".

```
ls = LinearSolve[s,"Method" -> "Cholesky"];
ls // InputForm
```

However, I'm stuck with what to do with this object to bring it in for the win.

Comment: OTOH, if the matrix in your application is actually SPD and tridiagonal, then no permutation is actually needed, and you can derive a bidiagonal Cholesky triangle (as you've shown in your example). But, you'll have to write the algorithm for producing it yourself…

Comment: With the help of `ls["Properties"]`, then you can achieve many useful results.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`LinearSolve[]` actually computes a *permuted* Cholesky decomposition; that is, it performs the decomposition $\mathbf P^\top\mathbf A\mathbf P=\mathbf G^\top\mathbf G$. To extract $\mathbf P$ and $\mathbf G$, we need to use some undocumented properties. Here's a demo:

```
mat = SparseArray[{Band[{2, 1}] -> -1., Band[{1, 1}] -> 2.,
                   Band[{1, 2}] -> -1.}, {5, 5}];

ls = LinearSolve[mat, Method -> "Cholesky"];
g = ls["getU"]; (* upper triangular factor *)
perm = ls["getPermutations"][[1]]; (* permutation vector *)
p = SparseArray[MapIndexed[Append[#2, #1] -> 1 &, perm]]; (* permutation matrix *)

p.Transpose[g].g.Transpose[p] == mat (* check! *)
   True
```

---

Here's a classical example of why permutation matrices are a must in sparse Cholesky decompositions.

Consider the following *upper arrowhead* matrix:

```
arr = SparseArray[{{1, j_} | {j_, 1} /; j != 1 -> -1., Band[{1, 1}] -> 3.}, {5, 5}];

ArrayPlot[arr]
```

[image: upper arrowhead]

Watch what happens after performing a Cholesky decomposition:

```
ArrayPlot[CholeskyDecomposition[arr]]
```

[image: Cholesky triangle of upper arrowhead]

Boom, fill-in. Imagine if this had been a $100\,000\times 100\,000$ upper arrowhead matrix!

If, however, we permute `arr` to a lower arrowhead matrix, like so:

```
exc = Reverse[IdentityMatrix[5]];
la = exc.arr.Transpose[exc];

ArrayPlot[CholeskyDecomposition[la]]
```

[image: Cholesky triangle of lower arrowhead]

What a difference a permutation makes!

For matrices with even more complicated sparsity patterns, it is doubtful if you can predict in advance that you won't get any disastrous fill-in if you insist on an unpermuted Cholesky triangle. Thus, all standard sparse Cholesky routines always perform some sort of permutation; though, as with any automatic routine of this sort, the permutation chosen might not be the most optimal, and yet yield something still good enough to work.

For reference, here's how `LinearSolve[]` does on an upper arrowhead:

```
lsar = LinearSolve[arr, Method -> "Cholesky"];
g = lsar["getU"];
ArrayPlot[g]
```

[image: Cholesky triangle from LinearSolve]

Comment: (As a further check that `LinearSolve[]` knows that it was fed an SPD matrix: `ls["getL"] == Transpose[ls["getU"]]`.)

Comment: Apologies for being "dense" but how would I get the upper form as shown by `CholeskyDecomposition`?

Comment: @Eric, I don't think there's a way to turn off the permutation in this case. Recall that direct linear solvers will often permute in an attempt to keep the triangular factors sparse (e.g. Cuthill-McKee).

Comment: A marvelous, helpful answer.  Thanks a million!

Comment: J.M. Why `ls = LinearSolve[{{1, 2}, {3, 4}}] ls["getPermutations"]` gives the error info?

Comment: @Shutao, probably a bug (it should return `{1, 2}`, cf. `LUDecomposition[]`), but remember that this is undocumented functionality, and subject to change without prior notice.

Comment: @J.M. OK, very appreciated. :)