# Obtaining the determinant from a LinearSolveFunction object

Tags: linear-algebra

I am working with matrices of which I need both the `LinearSolveFunction` and the determinant. My question is about something the documentation isn't entirely clear on. As far as I can tell, the `LinearSolveFunction` obtained from `LinearSolve` stores the LU decomposition of the matrix and from that it would be very easy to obtain the determinant.

```
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}]
ls = LinearSolve[mat]
ls[[2, 3]]
Det[mat]
Tr[ls[[2, 3, 1]], Times]
```

However, the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/AdvancedMatrixOperations.html) mentions that:

> When you create a `LinearSolveFunction` using `LinearSolve[m]`, this often works by decomposing the matrix `m` into triangular forms, and sometimes it is useful to be able to get such forms explicitly."

So my question is: when use the above code, am I guaranteed that I will find the LU decomposition of my matrix when I evaluate `ls[[2, 3]]`? I can see that this is certainly not true when using other `Method`s in `LinearSolve`, but the default `Automatic` method seems to do have the LU decompositions there. Then again: the method being `Automatic` suggests that it might do something different depending on the matrix I put in.

So all being said and done: is there a good, reliable way to obtain the determinant from a `LinearSolveFunction` object?

Comment: [A related math.SE question.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7788)

Comment: It depends on the method used (esp. the non-LU ones, such as `"Cholesky"`, `"Banded"`, `"Krylov"`, and even `"Multifrontal"`, which seems to produce a nonstandard LU decomposition).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In this case, you will need to use some *undocumented* functionality:

```
Tr[ls["getU"], Times] Signature[ls["getPermutations"][[1]]]
```

(currently away from my computer, so I'm only using *gedanken Mathematica*)

---

## Added much later

OK, apparently the `"getPermutations"` property is broken in version 11. In this case, we fall back on what you already know: that `ls[[2, 3]]` stores the equivalent of the result of `LUDecomposition[]`. Thus, adapting the solution in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/7790/):

```
mat = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {3, 3}];
ls = LinearSolve[mat];
{lu, perm, cond} = ls[[2, 3]]
Signature[perm] Tr[lu, Times]
```

tho of course this assumes that the structure of `LinearSolveFunction[]` won't be changed too much, in which case one prolly should've used `LUDecomposition[]` to begin with.