# Method option of function MatrixRank

Tags: matrix, undocumented, optional-arguments

By running `??MatrixRank`, I see that it has an optional argument named `Method`.

However, this argument is not in the documentation for `MatrixRank`, and I'd like to know what the available alternatives are (the default being Gaussian Elimination from what I can tell from the implementation notes in the documentation). Specifically, I have a very large very sparse matrix for which there may be a significantly faster algorithm than Gaussian Elimination (which seems to be the case from some research online)

Can anyone tell me what the possible values of `Method` are?

Comment: Not a precise answer to ypur question but might let you allow to compute the [matrix rank for huge sparse matrices](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/23056).

Comment: @Henrik thanks for the link. Unfortunately, the suggestion there uses UMFPACK, which as far as I can tell only works for numerical matrices; in my case, the matrix coefficients are actually polynomials with coefficients in a finite field, so a symbolic method is needed. Do you know of any other possible methods?

Comment: Nope. Sorry, this is not my field of expertise.