# Extract coefficient matrix $A$ from expression $f(x)$

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have expression: 
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=0}^{K-1}\sum_{j=0}^{N-1}a_{i,j}e^{ix}x^j.$$ 
I want to extract coefficient matrix $A$ from expression $f(x)$ where
$$A=\left(
\begin{array}{ccccc}
a_{0,0}& \cdots  & a_{0,j} & \cdots & a_{0,N-1} \\
\vdots & \cdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
 a_{i,0} & \cdots & a_{i,j} & \cdots & a_{i,N-1} \\
\vdots & \vdots & \cdots & \vdots\\
 a_{K-1,0} & \cdots & a_{K-1,j} & \cdots & a_{K-1,N-1} \\
\end{array}
\right).$$
For example: 
$$f(x)=-\frac{1}{2} e^{-x} x^3+\frac{1}{2} e^{-2 x} x^2+\frac{1}{2} e^{-x} x^2+2 e^{-2 x} x-2 e^{-x} x+e^{-2 x}-2 e^{-x}+1$$ and its $A$ is $$A=\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -2 & -2 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 1 & 2 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right).$$ 
Does Mathematica have specific function for this, or else can someone help me to develop a technique using existing functions in Mathematica?

Comment: Please post _Mathematica_ code.

Comment: This question may be useful http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/23039/how-to-read-off-coefficients-of-tensor-like-expression-in-a-speedy-way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple solution would be using `Coefficient`

```
p = Sum[c[i, j] x^i Exp[I j x], {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}];

Table[a[i, j] = Coefficient[Coefficient[p, x, i], Exp[I x], j]
 , {j, 0, 3}, {i, 0, 3}];

MatrixForm[%]
```

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 c(0,0) & c(0,1) & c(0,2) & c(0,3) \\
 c(1,0) & c(1,1) & c(1,2) & c(1,3) \\
 c(2,0) & c(2,1) & c(2,2) & c(2,3) \\
 c(3,0) & c(3,1) & c(3,2) & c(3,3) \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

> General structure

The syntax is applicable for any arbitrary polynomial $\sum_{i,j} x^i y^j$

```
p = Sum[c[i, j] x^i y^j, {i, 0, 3}, {j, 0, 3}];

var1 = x;
var2 = y;
Table[a[i, j] = Coefficient[Coefficient[p, var1, i], var2, j]
 , {j, 0, 3}, {i, 0, 3}];
```

For your given example

```
p = -1/2 Exp[-x] x^3 + 1/2 Exp[-2 x] x^2 + 1/2 Exp[-x] x^2
 + 2 Exp[-2 x] x - 2 Exp[-x] x + Exp[-2 x] - 2 Exp[-x] + 1

var1 = x ;
var2 = Exp[-x] ;
Table[a[i, j] = Coefficient[Coefficient[p, var1, i], var2, j]
 , {j, 0, 3}, {i, 0, 3}];

MatrixForm[%]
```

$
\left(
\begin{array}{cccc}
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 -2 & -2 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
 1 & 2 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{array}
\right)
$

You can easily extend it for more variable. In that case you would not be able to see it as a matrix, but the information will be stored in `a[i,j,...]`.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit, How can I change the second line if my p = 1 - E^(-3 x) + 3 E^(-2 x) - 3 E^-x + 3 E^(-2 x) x^2 - 3 E^-x x^2 +
    E^(-2 x) x^3 + E^-x x^3 + 1/4 E^(-2 x) x^4 - 1/4 E^-x x^4

Comment: just replace `Exp[I x]` by Exp[-x] in `Coefficient`. The idea is if you have $\sum_{i,j} x^i y^j$ then  `a[i, j] = Coefficient[Coefficient[p, y, j], x, i]`. In your case $y=e^{-x}$.

Comment: Thanks @Sumit. This is what exactly I needed, and this saves my time :)

Answer (score 3):

You can just use [`CoefficientList`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoefficientList):

```
p = -1/2 Exp[-x] x^3 + 1/2 Exp[-2 x] x^2 + 1/2 Exp[-x] x^2 + 2 Exp[-2 x] x -
    2 Exp[-x] x + Exp[-2 x] - 2 Exp[-x] + 1;
CoefficientList[p, {Exp[-x], x}] //TeXForm
```

> $\left(
> \begin{array}{cccc}
>  1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
>  -2 & -2 & \frac{1}{2} & -\frac{1}{2} \\
>  1 & 2 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 \\
> \end{array}
> \right)$